# Why my not-null columns become nullable in my CTE recursive query?

Tags: sql-server, cte, null, recursive

I have a simple hierarchical table. Let's say it has these columns:

```
Id, [Guid], ParentId, Title
```

Only `ParentId` is nullable. Other columns are not nullable.

I have created a recursive query to show me the path from the node up to the root. I have used CTE for this purpose. And this is my query:

```
with Anchor (Id, [Guid], ParentId, Title, [Path])
as
(
    select Id, [Guid], ParentId, Title, cast('' as nvarchar(100)) as [Path]
    from Hierarchies
    where ParentId is null
    union all
    select Hierarchies.Id, Hierarchies.[Guid], Hierarchies.ParentId, Hierarchies.Title, cast(Anchor.[Path] + '/' + Hierarchies.Title as nvarchar(100)) as [Path]
    from Hierarchies
    inner join Anchor
    on Hierarchies.ParentId = Anchor.Id
)
select 
    isnull(Anchor.Id, 0) as Id,
    isnull(Anchor.[Guid], newid()) as [Guid],
    Anchor.ParentId,
    Anchor.Title,
    Anchor.[Path]
from Anchor
```

The problem is that, when I turn this query into a view, the `Guid` column becomes nullable. I even used `isnull()` function to force it not to be null. And to my surprise, that `isnull` actually worked for the `Id` column. But it's not working for `Guid`.

What should I do? Why SQL Server has this behavior?

Answer (score 5):

The `NEWID()` function is not known for certain by the compiler to always return a value (even though you and I know that), so the only way to fix this is to use `ISNULL` again

```sql
ISNULL(ISNULL(Anchor.[Guid], NEWID()), CAST(0x0 AS uniqueidentifier))
```

The last parameter never actually gets executed.

Obviously, if you don't actually need `NEWID()` then you can just use the `CAST`:

```sql
ISNULL(Anchor.[Guid], CAST(0x0 AS uniqueidentifier))
```